# Dataset locked while running multiple programs

Tags: sas

I have a master table ( about 1TB in size) which is the primary source of data for all other program. When I submit 6 programs to run simultaneously it results in lock on the master table and other programs fail to run.

Is there a way to make sure master table is accessible by all the programs? some of the secondary programs are generating a sample out of the primary table while others are running some aggregation function out of it in order to create new data sets.

Comment: Have you tried setting the libname to read only?

Comment: Assuming the program is IO-bound (that is it spends most of its time waiting on data from the HDD), you might be better off running the programs sequentially.  Hard Drives go much slower under random access conditions and running the programs simultaneously will have you trying to access the same dataset a bunch of times in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

SAS won't lock the dataset when reading. How are you reading the table (please show code)?

If you're doing any modification to the dataset, that will lock it. Depending on the type of modification, it may be possible to lock with a row-level instead of a table-level lock by using the [CNTLLEV](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ledsoptsref/64757/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ta56uht2h9lgn1xwvs7uipanik.htm) dataset option; for example when appending new rows.

Be careful that your data steps aren't locking the table. For example, when you run

```
data mydataset;
  set mydataset;
  put _all_;
run;
```

In addition to putting all variables to the log, this block also writes the rows back to the dataset *even if they did not change*. It grabs a table-level lock when this runs. Instead, you should do this:

```
data _null_;
  set mydataset;
  put _all_;
run;
```